# Add or average specific cell value in different worksheets if they exist

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook that creates up to 3 (with the use of a macro) worksheets, and I need to average the value of a specific cell in each of the worksheets created. The problem is that the 2nd and/or 3rd worksheets may not be created at all, but I still need the value of the existent worksheets 
I tried the Average of the worksheets and cells but Excel calls for a file with the value of the "non-existent" cell.
The worksheets are called for example May - May1 (if created) - May2 (if created) and the location of the cell which value will be used is I7

`=AVERAGE(May!I7,May1!I7, May2!I7)` - Works when all the worksheets exist, but not when they are missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try,

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(May!I7, INDIRECT("'may1'!I7"), INDIRECT("may2!I7")),
 IFERROR(AVERAGE(May!I7,INDIRECT("'may1'!I7")),
 May!I7))
```

The INDIRECT functions are required or missing worksheet/cell references will irreversibly convert to #REF! errors.

Comment: Hello,
How can I copy the value of a single cell if the worksheet where the cell is, may not or may exist?